# find the limit: $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^x \cos x - (x+1)}{\tan x -\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> find
>
> $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^x \cos x - (x+1)}{\tan x -\sin x}$

i tried using l'hopital's rule, but it just gets very complicated very fast

edit: i made a mistake in the numerator (sorry!) its $(x+1)$

Comment: Is it $x+1$ on the numerator? otherwise the limit is infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use L'Hopital 3 times, and you'll get the answer. The expressions only look long at first glance, but a bunch of stuff cancel out:

> $$\lim_{{x} \to {0}} \frac{e^x\cos x - x - 1}{tanx - sinx} L(\frac00)= \lim_{{x} \to {0}} \frac{e^x\cos x - e^x\sin x  - 1}{\sec^2 x - \cos x} L(\frac00)= \lim_{{x} \to {0}} \frac{-2e^x\ sinx}{\sin x + 2\tan x\sec^2 x} L(\frac00)= \lim_{{x} \to {0}} \frac{-2e^x(\ sinx + \cos x )}{\sec^4 x(4\sin^2 x + \cos^5 x + 2)} = -\frac23$$

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x \to 0}{\expo{x}\cos\pars{x} - \pars{1 + x} \over \tan\pars{x} - \sin{x}}
=
\lim_{x \to 0}{x \over \tan\pars{x}}\,\bracks{x/2 \over \sin\pars{x/2}}^{2}{\expo{x} \cos\pars{x} - 1 - x \over x^{3}/2}
\\[3mm]&=
2\lim_{x \to 0}{\expo{x}\cos\pars{x} - x - 1 \over x^{3}}
=
2\lim_{x \to 0}{\expo{x}\cos\pars{x} - \expo{x}\sin\pars{x} - 1 \over 3x^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=
{2 \over 3}
\lim_{x \to 0}{\expo{x}\cos\pars{x} - \expo{x}\sin\pars{x} - \expo{x}\sin\pars{x} - \expo{x}\cos\pars{x} \over 2x}
=
-\,{2 \over 3}
\lim_{x \to 0}{\expo{x}\sin\pars{x} \over x}
\\[3mm]&=
-\,{2 \over 3}
\lim_{x \to 0}{\expo{x}\sin\pars{x} + \expo{x}\cos\pars{x} \over 1} =
\color{#0000ff}{\large -\,{2 \over 3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The denominator goes to zero, numerator goes to 2, so the limit is easy to compute.

**EDIT** With the changed problem, the easiest way is to use power series. The denominator is asymptotic to $x^3/2,$ the numerator to $-x^3/3,$ so the limit should be $-3/2.$ But do the computation yourself.

Comment: i believe that the limit does not exist (+- infinity), this question is from MVT, LHR, and Taylor Series homework, can this be solved like that?

Comment: Well, all I used was Taylor series, so you can too.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but you have the wrong end limit...

Comment: @anorton don't say you weren't warned.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^x\cos(x)-\left(x+1\right)}{\tan(x)\:-\sin(x)}\right)
& = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+o\left(x^3\right)\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o\left(x^2\right)\right)-\left(x+1\right)}{\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+o\left(x^3\right)\right)\:-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o\left(x^3\right)\right)}\right)
\\& = \lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{-x^5-3x^4-4x^3}{12}+o\left(x^2\right)}{\frac{x^3}{2}+o\left(x^3\right)}\right)
\\& = \color{red}{-\frac{2}{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Solved with Taylor expansion

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x} {x^{3}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x} {x} \cdot \frac{1-\cos x} {x^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos x} =\frac{1}{2}$$ and therefore the desired limit is given by
\begin{align} 
L&=2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}\cos x - 1-x}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&=2\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}+\frac{e^{x}+\cos x-x- 2 }{x^{3}}\right)\notag\\
&=2\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}-\sin x-1}{3x^{2}}\right)\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)} \notag\\
&=-1+\frac{2}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x}-\cos x} {2x}\text{ (via L'Hospital's Rule)} \notag\\
&=-1+\frac{1}{3}\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}+x\cdot\frac{1-\cos x} {x^{2}}\right)\notag\\
&=-1+\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{2}{3}\notag
\end{align}
Note that before applying L'Hospital's Rule it is desirable to perform algebraic manipulation so that the process of differentiating the numerator and denominator is easy and leads to simpler expressions.

Answer (score 0):

l'hospital's rule is the right way to go. The first derivative will still give you $0/0$, but the second derivative should solve this problem.